# Kendo Grid Hierarchical View: How to avoid auto open first row

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a hierarchical grid. How can I avoid that the first row is expanded when the site is loaded?

regards

Comment: Can you show some code? Like lets see what you have implemented.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your kendo hierarchical grid expands the first row and since you have not shared your code, lets assume that you are binding the grid with jQuery.

Now to not to allow the grid to expand the first row, all you have to do is remove

```
this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
```

from the `dataBound` event.

Here is a **[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/FBQZQ/120/)**. See the commented code in the example.

Comment: Thank you very much, you knew we were doing just as the example did without understanding why xD

Comment: You're Welcome! Happy new year btw! :)